# Merge multiple object to one in angular 8

Tags: javascript

I have a multiple object within a array,

```
[
  {Mat: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Kan: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Eng: {Max: 25, Min: 9}}
]
```

How do I merge multiple objects to one like below,

```
[
  {
    Mat: {Max: 25, Min: 9},
    Kan: {Max: 25, Min: 9},
    Eng: {Max: 25, Min: 9}
  }
]
```

Comment: This looks more specific to TS/JS that to angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to iterate over and merge the objects with [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Then you can wrap it with array.

```js
var arr = [
  {Mat: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Kan: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Eng: {Max: 25, Min: 9}}
]

var obj = [arr.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...acc, ...cur}), {})]

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple and one-liner**

```js
const data = [
    { Mat: { Max: 25, Min: 9 } },
    { Kan: { Max: 25, Min: 9 } },
    { Eng: { Max: 25, Min: 9 } }
]
const result = [Object.assign(...data)]
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a very basic approach if you are nof familiar with pipes and streams.

```
const array = [
  {Mat: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Kan: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Eng: {Max: 25, Min: 9}}
]

const resultingObject = {};
for(const obj of array){
  for(const key of Object.keys(obj)){
    resultingObject[key] = obj[key];
  }
}

console.log(resultingObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ES6** Spread syntax:

```
let array = [
  {Mat: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Kan: {Max: 25, Min: 9}},
  {Eng: {Max: 25, Min: 9}}
];
let newObject={};
array.forEach(item=> newObject = {...newObject,...item});
console.log(newObject);
```

**ES5** Object.assign:

```
array.forEach(function(item){ Object.assign(newObject,item) });
```

**for of** syntax:

```
for(var item of array)
  Object.assign(newObject,item);
```